# It can not be executed robomongo

Tags: linux, mongodb

I submit this error, when I try to run the robomongo application.
How can I solve it?

**I have Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (`core 'generated)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
ldd `which robomongo`
```

which will give you a list of linked libraries used by the executable.

You should find a line like this one (the number can vary of course)

`libxcb.so.1 => /usr/bin/../lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fc20b8f4000)`

if the library is marked as not found you need to install (or reinstall) it.

If it is present, check if it is installed correctly, you should find something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 May 22  2016 /usr/bin/../lib/libxcb.so -> libxcb.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 May 22  2016 /usr/bin/../lib/libxcb.so.1 -> libxcb.so.1.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 166864 May 22  2016 /usr/bin/../lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```